# Opaque controls on semi-transparent control

Tags: wpf, controls, transparency

I have a StackPanel with some Buttons in it.  I want the StackPanel to be semi-transparent, but the buttons to remain opaque.  I've been googling for a while but still can't figure this out.  I can find solutions for having opaque controls on a semi-transparent window, but not for opaque controls on a semi-transparent control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say semi-transparent StackPanel, you certainly mean the StackPanel's `Background`. You can always set that to a Brush with an Opacity less than 1. In case of a solid-color background, that would be a [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity=".5"/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

or you simply use a color with an appropriate alpha value:

```
<StackPanel Background="#7FFF0000">
```

Comment: Well dad gum, that's way better than my solution and I just went from feeling smart to kinda dumb for not having thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah!!  I figured it myself right after I asked (and it brought the same rewarding feeling I always get after solving a puzzle on Zelda).

Instead of putting my opaque controls inside of a semi-transparent control, I placed a border control with an opacity setting of .5 in a Grid and then added my StackPanel to the same Grid location so that it just overlayed it.